# Suppressing error message when downloading files

Tags: php, error-handling, docusignapi

I'm currently using the php client for docusign (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client) and everytime I call `DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi::getDocument` I get a message like

```
[INFO] Written ##### byte to /tmp/######. Please move the file to a proper folder or delete the temp file after processing.
```

This is apparently triggered by this line (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/ObjectSerializer.php#L260)

```
error_log("[INFO] Written $byte_written byte to $filename. Please move the file to a proper folder or delete the temp file after processing.\n", 3, Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->getDebugFile());
```

I tried pretty much everything I could think of, using @, setting error_reporting to 0, setting the debugfile to `php://stderr`, to `/dev/null`, all to no avail.

I'm using this method in the context of a custom Symfony command if that's of any use.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be an error, just informative. Have you tried commenting out the line?

Comment: Editing a library is a bad practice, my whole project is composer-based, short of forking that library, there's really no way I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is outputting that text as an informational message to the system log. I understand your desire to not see it. [I have filed an issue against the SDK about this.](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/issues/27)

In the meantime, I suggest that you git fork the SDK and comment out that line.